# Relation between coercivity and boundness from below

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, coercive

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$f(x)\ge \| x\|.$$

It is clear that, if $\|x\|\to +\infty$, it follows that $f(x)\to +\infty$, so $f$ is coercive.
However, the inequality $f(x)\ge \| x\|$ also states that $f$ is bounded from below.

My question is: it is true that all coercive funtions are bounded from below (I don't think so..) or it a special case?

I am sorry for my possibly dumb question, but I am a bit in trouble right now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Fred thank you. But if I have the additional property that $f(x)\ge \| x\|$, it is bounded from below too, isn't it?

Comment: @Fred Why does g to infinity  if $x$ goes to - infinity

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.

Comment: @Fred see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is additionally lower semicontinuous, it is also bounded from below. Indeed, there is some $\delta \ge 0$ such that
$$
f(x) \ge 0 \qquad\forall \|x\| \ge \delta.$$
Moreover, on the compact set $[-\delta,\delta]$, the lower semicontinuous function $f$ attains its infimum. Therefore,
there is $x_0 \in [-\delta,\delta]$ with
$$
f(x) \ge f(x_0) \qquad\forall x_0\in [-\delta,\delta].$$
This shows that $f$ is bounded from below by $\min\{0,f(x_0)\}$.

Comment: "Additionally" with which other assumption?

Comment: With "coercive". You asked whether coercive functions are bounded from below and I answered that we need additionally "lsc".

Comment: You have a lower bound for $|x|\ge\delta$ first and then for $|x|\le\delta$, so you have a lower bound for  all $\delta$ just taking the minimum, isn't it? Nice way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that $f(x)>|x|$ you know that $f(x)>-1$ so it’s bounded from below , In general coercive function need not be bounded below for example you can let your function be $\log(|x|)$  and $0$ for $x=0$ it’s coercive but not bounded below

Comment: Thank you for your answer, clear. But why you say that $f(x)>-1$?

Comment: @User1010 Because $|x|$ is always $\ge 0$

Comment: Yes, so also $f(x)>-\varepsilon$ holds true.

Comment: @User1010 Yes, Does this answer your question?

Comment: @User1010 Why did you unaccept my answer ?

Comment: @User1010 and why did you remove upvote ?

Comment: I think gerw answer better fits my needs. I missed the upvote, I give it back.